# How to show progress indicator while looping ajax .forEach() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to display progress indicator while ajax request looping using .forEach()

example

> **2 of 12 success**

html code

```
<h2 class="progress_text"></h2>
<a onclick="getdata()">Get Data</a>
```

jquery code

```
var arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','7','8','9','10','11','12']
var sum = arr.length
var progress = 0

function getdata(){
 arr.forEach(start_getdata)
}

function start_getdata(value, index, array) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/get_data",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: value,
            },
            success: function(data) {
               $(".progress_text").html(""+progress ++ +" of "+ sum +" success")
            },
            error: function(x, e) {
                console.log("Gagal")
            }
        });
    }
```

my code only show once when .forEach() done execute

please answer if someone has same problem

thank you

Comment: This is because you have `async: false` - which is deprecated in browsers because of this very reason.  Javascript is **single-threaded** - ie only one line of javascript can run at a time, and that includes updating the UI.

Comment: is there any suggestion i can use to achieve my goal ? thanks

Comment: Suggestion would be to stop using `async:false` and implement an *ajax queue* (so you don't overload/ddos your server with too many ajax requests at the same time).